# Create a search query and display the results based on the selected checkboxes (difficulty grouping results)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have a php page that display multiple keywords (checkboxes) for example areas such as Narberth, Pembrokeshire, Carmarthenshire etc as well as other things.

So far i have created a way to do this and display the data separately in tables. What I'm having trouble with is showing the rows with multiple keywords associated with them first.

So if the user searched "Narberth" and "Pembrokeshire" the results would show any documents with both those keywords in first then anything with just "narberth" and just "pembrokshire" afterwords.

I listed my code for what I've worked out so far :

```
<form method="post">
<table border="1px solid" width="60%">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="1">Narberth </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="2">James Brothers </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="3">Mabinogion </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="4">Pembrokeshire </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="5">Pubs </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="keywords[]" value="6">Coastal Paths </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name = "submit">
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach( $_REQUEST['keywords'] as $keywordID )
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_index m
inner join tbl_filekeywords r on m.file_id = r.file_id
where r.keyword_id = '".$keywordID."'");

$keywordname = mysql_query ("SELECT keyword FROM tbl_keywords WHERE keyword_id = '".$keywordID."'");
$KeywordName = mysql_fetch_row($keywordname);
$KeywordName = $KeywordName[0];

echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>
<th colspan='2'>".$KeywordName."</th>
<tr>
<th>File ID</th>
<th>Filename</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['file_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['file'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
mysql_free_result($result);
}
}?>
```

P.S There is another alternative that i developed that lumps all the files into one table which is fine but i still want to stop the same files appearing multiple times for each keyword and would rather the ones with more than one keyword to be prioritized and displayed on top.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['keywords']) && !empty($_POST['keywords'])){
foreach($_POST['keywords'] as $key=>$value){
if($value==1) $keywords[] = "keyword_id='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'";
}
$keywords = implode(' OR ', $keywords);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_index m inner join tbl_filekeywords r on m.file_id = r.file_id WHERE $keywords";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>
<tr>
<th>File ID</th>
<th>Filename</th>
<th>Keyword_ID</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['file_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['file'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['keyword_id'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

And finally the tables are set up like:

```
tbl_index : file_id, file

tbl_keywords : keyword_id, keyword

tbl_filekeywords : file_id, keyword_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, wellcome to SO. Post answer delay is due to non synthesized question. In next questions remember to include only relevant code to question.

Lets supose that `tbl_index` and `tbl_filekeywords` tables are in 1:N relationship.

First of all, in php you can get `$keywords` as a string list of selected keywords Example:

```
$keywords = " 1, 5, 12,  24"
```

Now you can rank tbl_filekeywords in this way. We named `rank view`:

```
select 
  r.file_id, 
  sum( case when r.keyword_id in ( $keywords  ) then 1 else 0 end ) as rank
from
  tbl_filekeywords r
group by 
  r.file_id
```

Last step is to join `rank view` with tbl_index:

```
   select t.*
   from 
     tbl_index t left outer join
     ( HERE PREVIUS QUERY ) r
          on r.file_id = t.file_id
   order by
     coalesce( r.rank, 0 )
```

Let us to know if this runs and it is a solution for you. If not, explain how can we improve answer!

**Edited due OP Comment**

I don't have your database schema, but it seems that `file_id` is PK for `tbl_index`. If this is the case, the query don't produce duplicates. Notice that first query, `rank view`, only has a row for each `file_id` due to group by clause. Because this, join don't produce duplicates. For me the final query is:

```
   select t.*
   from 
     tbl_index t inner join                 <--No dups
     ( 
       select 
         r.file_id, 
         count(*) as rank
       from
         tbl_filekeywords r
       where
         r.keyword_id in ( $keywords  )
       group by 
         r.file_id                          <--No dups
     ) r2
          on r2.file_id = t.file_id
   order by
      r2.rank
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I've not dealt with ranks before so this is new to me. As far as I can tell this will order the rows in an appropriate way But won't i still get duplicates? For example the tbl_filekeywords looks like this:

file_id :- 1 , 1, 1, 2, 2
keyword_id :- 1, 3, 7, 1 , 2

The problem is i want these to only appear once when the table is generated online. At the moment when i search keywords 1 and 3, file_id appears once for each keyword. Thanks :)

Comment: After testing this it seems to work perfectly, the only thing is that the file_id with the greatest importance is being showed at the bottom  of the list. how would i go about swapping this so it shows at the top? Sorry for the delay and thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Haha never mind i just added desc after the order by :P obvious change on my part :)